# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sass-loader'

Tags: webpack, sass-loader

New to webpack.  Trying to get sass-loader to play nice with my react project, have followed tutorials.  Config seems correct, but result is always "Can't resolve 'sass-loader'".

I suspect this is some glaringly obvious error, but no amount of searching for it or googling has led me to it yet.  Any help appreciated.

**Error**

```
ERROR in ./ui/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sass-loader' in '/root/src'
 @ ./ui/index.js 19:0-33
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true babel-polyfill ./ui/index.js
```

**What I have done so far (on said pre-existing react project):**

`npm i --save-dev node-sass sass-loader`

package.json, under devDependencies

```
"node-sass": "^4.7.2",
"sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
"webpack": "~2.2.1",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "~1.12.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "~2.20.0",
"webpack-node-externals": "~1.6.0"
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './src/App';

require('./src/styles/main.scss');

ReactDOM.render(<HashRouter><App /></HashRouter>, 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

webpack.config.react.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const sourcePath = path.join(__dirname, './ui');
const extractStyle = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');

//======break to module rules=======

module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      include: sourcePath,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['react'],
      },
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      include: sourcePath,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: extractStyle.extract('sass-loader?sourceMap'),
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      exclude: sourcePath,
      loader: extractStyle.extract('css-loader'),
    },
  ],
},

//======= break again for plugins =====

plugins: [
  extractStyle,
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'ui/index.html',
    title: 'name',
  }),
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
  }),
]
```

Possible confounder: This is all running in a development docker container.  It's been rebuilt and npm install has run again, though.

Comment: False alarm - npm wasn't handling installation correctly.  Removing the node_modules directory and rebuilding fixed most of our problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As in above comment - false alarm.  Somewhere between Docker image caching and npm, the sass-loader and node-sass modules were reported as being installed, while not actually being installed.   The usual `rm node_modules` and rebuilding with no cache trick fixed it.

Comment: Same here. I always need to `docker-compose down app;docker-compose build --no-cache app` after restarting a container with newly installed packages. Never found a way to avoid that

Comment: it should be  
`rm -r node_modules`
to work

Answer (score 42):

Go to the project and run below two commands

```
npm install sass-loader -D

npm install node-sass -D
```

Comment: ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
ERR! dev sass-loader@"*" from the root project
ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@5.40.0

Answer (score 19):

This issue may be a result of caching. There's no need to restart the project.

Run the following  on the terminal

```
rm -r node_modules
```

```
npm install
```

```
npm install -D sass-loader@^10 sass
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was due to version conflict between 'sass-loader' and 'webpack'.

In **package.json** file, I down graded the `sass-loader` version to `"^8.0.2"`, then I ran `npm update` command.

Here is the final *package.json* code

```
{
  "name": "My Vue3 App",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "^8.1.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer did help me: [Problem Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941009/npm-install-d-sass-loader-node-sass-vue-js-2021)

You may try

> npm install -D sass-loader@^10 sass

Answer (score 0):

For my nuxt app, deploying using AWS CodePipeline (Bitbucket) to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. What helped prepending "npm install sass-loader"(this have worked too "npm install")to build script, not sure if it is best way but it works for now.

Procfile

```
web: npm run deploy
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "deploy": "npm install sass-loader && npm run build && npm run start"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use Below Command

```
npm install sass-loader -D
```

Go to webpack.config.js

```
module: {
        rules: [
           
       {     
          test: /\.scss$/,
         
            {          
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                  
                  'css-loader',
                  'sass-loader'<-----------------------sass loader
                ]}
    
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I had this problem and I solved it when I installed my project

```
vue create project
```

next
[image]

select manually then

[image]

finally

[image]

Answer (score -1):

i am uninstall package and was this error for vue3 -> Failed to resolve loader: sass-loader
You may need to install it.

removed for all uninstall packages but i was a to forget in line change

**src/App.vue**

-OLD

< style lang="scss" >
.
.

-NEW - THIS TRUE

< style >
.
.
< /style >