# Problems with React app compiling all of a sudden

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Fresh JS dev here, completely new to modern day Javascript, modules, etc. Have no idea what I'm doing. I was tasked with creating a tech-stack for a new web client that uses React. Started an app with `npx create-react-app`. Was working just fin when all of a sudden I get the following errors when I saved a change to one of my components. All I did was add a paragraph tag.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js 7:34-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'C:\Development\Repos\Node\se\client\node_modules\sass-loader\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "url": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js 8:35-50

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Development\Repos\Node\se\client\node_modules\sass-loader\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/utils.js 14:34-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'C:\Development\Repos\Node\se\client\node_modules\sass-loader\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "url": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/utils.js 15:35-50

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Development\Repos\Node\se\client\node_modules\sass-loader\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js 116:14-29

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'C:\Development\Repos\Node\se\client\node_modules\sass'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
    - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "util": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js 118:12-25

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Development\Repos\Node\se\client\node_modules\sass'
```

I have no idea what to do here. I've been down a rabit hole of answers across Google and stack overflow, none of which have helped.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47447199/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-sass-loader), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649677/node-error-resolve-url-loader-css-error), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161839/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs-in). I'm grasping at straws now...I have no idea what polyfills are. Pretend an entry level JS developer is given the task of creating a full fledged enterpris React app in a month. Because thats exactly what happened, and we have no React devs on any of our teams.

Comment: Probably related [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11756)

Comment: @SergeySosunov so basically my options are A) Find polyfills for the modules I need or B) drop those modules?

Comment: Im not recommending anything, just because I had no errors like this one so I have no idea what will work, but, there is also 3rd option as I can see, get rid of CRA, I found an interesting and pretty hot [PR](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/pull/5487) recently.